# Python : Java throws equivalent in python

Tags: java, python, exception, throws

Not attempting to compare the languages but just for knowledge,

Is there any way to have equivalent of java `throws` keyword/functionality  in Python?

or the way we can recognize checked exception thrown by any method at static time?

or Passing(chaining) exception handling responsibility?

Java:

```
public void someMethod() throws SomeException
{

}
```

Python:

```
@someDecorator  # any way to do?
def someMethod():
    pass
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you can't have statically typed arguments, you can't have static throws declarations. For instance, there's no way for me to annotate this function:

```
def throw_me(x):
    raise x
```

Or even this one:

```
def call_func(f):
    f()  # f could throw any exception
```

What you can do is make it an error to throw any type of exception other than those specified:

```
from functools import wraps

class InvalidRaiseException(Exception):
    pass

def only_throws(E):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
            except E:
                raise
            except InvalidRaiseException:
                raise
            except Exception as e:
                raise InvalidRaiseException("got %s, expected %s, from %s" % (
                    e.__class__.__name__, E.__name__, f.__name__)
                )

        return wrapped
    return decorator
```

```
@only_throws(ValueError)
def func(x):
    if x == 1:
        raise ValueError
    elif x == 2:
        raise Exception
```

```
>>> func(0)
>>> func(1)
ValueError
>>> func(2)
InvalidRaiseException: got Exception, expected ValueError, from func
```

Comment: I found http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498131-checked-exceptions/ is something equivalent

Answer (score 12):

There is no standard equivalent of this in Python as far as I know, and it's not necessary either. The best you can do is indicate in the docstring what exceptions/errors are raised in what circumstances, and leave it to whoever is using your functions to work out the rest.

In Java, the throws clause is a sort of bookkeeping. For example,

```
try {
    foo();
} catch (IOException ioe) {

}
```

doesn't compile unless `foo` is known to have the potential of throwing an `IOException`. The analog in Python:

```
try:
    foo()
except IOError as ioe:
    pass
```

compiles regardless. There is no concept of "checked vs unchecked".

Answer (score 8):

As an addition:

Python introduced Type-Hints for documentation purpose in PEP 484:

```
def foo(bar: str) -> int:
    pass
```

As answered in [Python type hinting with exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44282268/python-type-hinting-with-exceptions) and https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#exceptions there is currently no way to define the Exceptiones which are raised by a function.