# Can I determine what errors a function will raise from typing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, typing, code-documentation

Let's say I have the function:

```py
def foo(integer: int) -> int:
    if integer < 0:
        raise ValueError("The integer must be positive")

    return integer * 2
```

If I look at the signature for this function, it will only tell me that it takes an `int` and returns an `int`.

However, it would be really nice to know that it also has the chance of raising a `ValueError` in case I need to catch that.

Is there any way to put what errors a function raises into the types, or is this just something that should go into the docstring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Docstrings would be a good practice.

Also:  [Python type hinting with exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44282268/python-type-hinting-with-exceptions)