# Reference position of index without value

Tags: python, pointers, indexing

As of Python 3, you can explicitly declare variables by type:

```
x: int = 3
or:
def f(x: int):
    return x
```

How would I do this with index numbers?

I am trying to maintain the address of the value without calculating the value directly…

Comment: What do you mean by "*index number*"? Can you provide an example?

Comment: N[1] where 1 is the position (index number) of something in N

Comment: Then it's an `int`

Comment: The point was that x is an explicit variable…

Comment: Do you mean you want to type hint the item at index `N[1]`? As in "The second item in `N` must be a string"? And what is `N`—a tuple? A list? A dictionary? These all have different considerations.

Answer (score 1):

**Type Hint** doesn't raise exception when you assign incorrect type of value.
It's currently only known for documentation. See in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44282299/8170215

Still, if you wish to define the type hint for dictionary, you can do:

```py
from typing import Dict

x: Dict[int, str] = {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}
```

which doesn't raise exception when you assign something like `x = 'some string'` or `x['a'] = 'b'`

If you want python to raise `AssertionError`, you can use:

```py
# No exception
x = {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}
assert all(isinstance(key, int) for key in x)

# AssertionError
x = {'a': 'a', 2: 'b'}
assert all(isinstance(key, int) for key in x)
```

Or, you can use libraries like [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/)

Answer (score -1):

Is this how you want it?

```
x = [3]

a= x.index(3)

print (a)
```

which outputs 0

the `int` is not neccessary actually, and what is the `or` for?

Comment: Sorry lol the or wasn’t code.