# Is there a Python linter to check for a missing `raise` keyword?

Tags: python, static-analysis, pylint

I have seen the following pattern several times:

```
if value > MAX_VALUE:
    ApplicationError("value is too large")

# value is in range now
use_value(value)
```

There is an obvious but relatively easy-to-miss bug here: the `raise` keyword is missing from `ApplicationError`. An exception object is constructed but not raised, and an invalid `value` continues to the rest of the function.

We use flake8, pyright, and a select set of pylint lints. My expectation is that *some sort* of static analysis tool would find this problem:

- either by detecting that I'm creating an exception instance and not raising it,
- or (easier) that I'm creating an instance of a class, but not storing the result (this could be used for side-effects but it's definitely an antipattern, right?)
- or (most general) that there is a function call with unused result

The last option seems like something mypy/pyright should be capable of catching, at least, but I'm completely unable to find *any sort* of linter for this.

Is there a linting tool for Python code that can detect this problem (missing `raise` keyword) and how to configure it to do so?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: the question is, what linter or static analysis tool can detect this problem?
i thought that the title and the last line makes it obvious, but apparently not, so thanks for the notice, I edited the question

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44282268/python-type-hinting-with-exceptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pointless-exception-statement` in pylint does what you want, this is a builtin check that is activated by default, see https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/messages/warning/pointless-exception-statement.html