# Type-hint a Python function that *never* raises exception

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have an async Python contextmanager that will (among other things) catch any exceptions thrown in the with-block.

Is there a way to indicate to my users that doing a try-catch over it is a bad idea (as it will catch any exceptions).

I think the answer is ”no, its impossible”, but couldnt find a definitive answer. I also understand that a function *can* always raise an exception, but in my particular case, wrapping this in a try-catch will almost always be a mistake.

Comment: While it might be a mistake, it will be a harmless mistake. Just document it and don't worry about it.

Comment: There is no way to do this currently, see linked question and doc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44282268/python-type-hinting-with-exceptions.

Adding this info to your docstring makes sense to me.

Comment: There's currently no way to specify what exceptions a function might raise, nor a way to say that it doesn't raise any. And it doesn't seem like there's any plan to add them, because Guido is against it.

Comment: And it seems like guaranteeing no exceptions is a poor idea: What if there's a bug in the code that's supposed to catch all exceptions?

Comment: See also: https://discuss.python.org/t/extend-type-hints-to-cover-exceptions/23788, https://discuss.python.org/t/pep-484-when-will-we-have-syntax-for-exceptions/26936 and many more.